# Is the order of RKF45 in python 4th or 5th order?

Tags: scipy, differential-equations

Howdy just had a numerical analysis question about RKF45. The documentation is a little mysterious in terms if is 4th or 5th order, and even on the wikipedia page "is a method of order O(h^4) with an error estimator of order O(h^5)"

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method

Is the idea you first do the 4th order method, and then the interpolate of the numerical solution is 5th order to the true solution? So overall the output of this numerical method is 5th order?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have changed the method name, but that might be wrong, meaning you found the wrong wikipedia page. The method in RK45 is the [Dormand-Prince (4)5 method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormand%E2%80%93Prince_method)

Comment: I meant to add: Feel free to change it back or better make it uniquely clear what method you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### classical embedded methods like Fehlberg 4(5) aka RKF45

The method can proceed with the state updates of its 4th or 5th order method, designed for the 4th, nowadays used with 5th. The step size is variable, the optimal step size is always determined for the 4th order method, with the difference to the 5th order method serving as estimate of the local error, which in most cases is very accurate.

The relation between error tolerance and number of ODE function evaluations will mostly correspond to the 4th order, for example dividing the error tolerance by 16 should result in a step size sequence that is locally about half of the original sequence, doubling the number of ODE function evaluations.

If an exact solution is computable, the error of the numerical integration should be proportional to the tolerance if the 4th order steps are taken, and proportional to the power 5/4 of the tolerance if the 5th order steps are taken.

### Extrapolation methods like DoPri (4)5 aka ode45 or RK45

The method proceeds with the values of the 5th order method. It uses a variable step size that is controlled via the difference between the 4th order method and the 5th order method, augmented to behave loosely like the actual local (unit step) error of the 5th order method. Despite being more a guidance to the local error size, it is good enough for the actual error to remain in the region of or below the error tolerance and for the step size to not leave the stability region of the 5th order method. The method was explicitly designed to show this behavior.

For test equations that are smooth, one can thus expect that in a log-log diagram of number of evaluations of the ODE function vs. given error tolerance or actual error against an exact solution you get a curve that is mostly linear with slope about 5. (One would of course compute it the other way, get number of function evaluations and actual error for some spread of error tolerances.)

See https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/math/vble.pdf for some experiments with low-order embedded methods, starting with [using the Euler method as embedded method in the explicit midpoint and Heun method.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437080/adaptive-step-size-for-euler-method-how-to-create/4582092#4582092)